# How to close target = _blank page in selenium without close driver?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have a two like like below

```
<body>
    <a href="contact.php" target="_blank">contact</a>
    <a href="test.php" target="_blank">Sest</a>
</body>
```

After click on link page has open in new tab , I want to close this tab without close driver, Is it possible ? I have tried below code but not working.

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//a[contains(text(),'contact') or contains(text(),'est')]")

link.click()

driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch between windows by using `driver.window_handles` to identify all the windows currently open in your `driver`'s browser. Then you can move between them using `driver.switch_to_window(). Here's an example:

```py
tabs = driver.window_handles #get list of open windows
driver.switch_to_window(tabs[1])
driver.close() #close the current window
driver.switch_to_window(tabs[0]) #return to first window
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, been working on this one for a while, great answer, nice and simple worked immediately, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A tab is nothing more than another window (from the eyes of selenium)

To close a window you must switch to it, then call `driver.close()`. 
**This does NOT cause selenium to quit the driver itself**, which I suspect is what you might be afraid of.

To switch to a window, you'll need the window ID.

`driver.current_window_handle` gives you the window you're currently focused. 
`driver.window_handles` will give you a list of all the windows open. 
Assuming you only have two windows open, it should be easy to identify the one you want to close.

Lastly, don't forget to switch back to the original window.  Closing a window does not automatically move your focus back to a window.

```
driver.switch_to.window(window_id)
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(original_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's like a real browser. If you close the one and only tab, the browser closes himself. Try not to open the second Tab in a new Tab, just use the other you don't want anymore.